# Using dates from node red to influxdb in Grafana

Tags: date, grafana, influxdb, node-red

I am collecting data from my electricity meter. Every day at 3AM I get a usage figure for the previous day which I send into InfluxDB via NodeRed.

The data is generated by a little Python file and consists of a JSON string:

```
{"UsageDate": "2022-08-14", "Usage": 9.622}
```

Each reading arrives during the day following UsageDate, so when I send it to InfluxDB it gets a timestamp which is actually a day late.
I want to display this data as a bar chart/histogram in Grafana - but I don't know how to use the dates in UsageDate (which is stored in InfluxDB as a string at the moment) as the x-axis of my graph.

Can I persuade Grafana to use that date, or do I need to do something clever to make InfluxDB timestamp my data for the day it belongs to, rather than the day it arrives in InfluxDB.

Comment: What have you tried and how didn't it work?

Comment: Influxdb has no datatype for date, so I've tried a variety of string formats for date, but I can't make Grafana see these as dates and use them as x-axis . I've tried putting a timestamp into a field called time (or Time). These get stored as floats in InfluxDB and ignored by Grafana. The influxdb documentation suggests that it only timestamps data that arrives without a timestamp so I think my question is basically 'how do I add a utc timestamp (the value of which i specify, rather than being now())to a node red message so that influxdb will use it rather than applying one at time of arrival?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73363590/edit) the question when adding details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is transformations. You need to do 2 things:

1. Change the type to date: add transformation "Convert field type" to convert the field UsageDate to a time (check to give the correct format).
2. Rename the field UsageDate to "Time" using a transformation "Organize fields". This will make it the x-Axis of a Time series panel.

[Transformations in my configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9viYS.png)

Comment: THanks - that worked. I had to specify a custom query in Grafana to get both my fields into the query, and it's worth pointing out that the field conversion transformation is not available in older versions of Grafana (I was on v8x and upgraded to 9 this morning). So many thanks.